IOS - Flutter Sound does not record
using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound
I have the following code


class RecordYourNameScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const RecordYourNameScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _RecordYourNameScreenState createState() => _RecordYourNameScreenState();
}

class _RecordYourNameScreenState extends ConsumerState<RecordYourNameScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isRecordingDone = false;
  bool isRecording = false;
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  FlutterSoundRecorder? _recorder;
  String? _path;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestPermissions();
    _recorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
    initRecorder();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    )..repeat(reverse: true);

    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller);
  }

  Future<void> requestPermissions() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.microphone,
      Permission.storage, // for saving files
    ].request();

    if (statuses[Permission.microphone] != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      // Handle permission denial
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
            content: Text('Microphone permission is required to record audio')),
      );
      return;
    }

    if (statuses[Permission.storage] != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      // Handle storage permission denial
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
            content: Text('Storage permission is required to save recordings')),
      );
      return;
    }

    // Proceed with recording and saving
  }

  Future<void> initRecorder() async {
    await _recorder!.openRecorder();
  }

  Future<void> startRecording() async {
    var status = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      zlog.v("startRecording");
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      // Define the path to store the recording in a proper directory
      _path = '${directory.path}/audio_example.aac';

      // Start recording
      await _recorder!.startRecorder(
        toFile: _path,
        codec:
            Codec.aacADTS, // You can also use other codecs like mp3, wav, etc.
      );
      setState(() {
        isRecording = true;
      });
    } else {
      zlog.v("startRecording failed ${status.name}");
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            'Failed to start recording - ${status.name}',
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> stopRecording() async {
    await _recorder!.stopRecorder();
    setState(() {
      isRecording = false;
      isRecordingDone = true;
    });
    // Add your stop recording logic here
  }

  Future<void> saveRecording() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    if (_path != null) {
      if (await checkIfFileExists(_path!)) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              'Recording uploading...',
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              'Recording not found',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      final url = await uploadRecordingToCloudinary(_path!);
      if (url != null) {
        zlog.v('Recording uploaded successfully: $url');
        var name = ref.read(appProviderProvider.notifier).userName;
        if (name != null) {
          await sendNamePronunciationAPI(name, url);
          zlog.v('Recording sent to server: $url');
          ref.read(appProviderProvider.notifier).setNameRecordingExist(true);
        } else {
          zlog.v('Failed to upload recording');
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(
                'Failed to upload recording',
              ),
            ),
          );
        }

        // Add your logic to handle the uploaded URL
      } else {
        zlog.v('Failed to upload recording');
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              'Failed to upload recording',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AlarmListScreen()),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



Works great on android but fails silently on ios
I ask for permission
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need access to your microphone to record audio.</string>
    <key>NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need access to save your recordings.</string>

but the recording is generating an empty file
I don't have any clue why?
NOTE:

the code run with no issue on android, fails only on ios
tried different codec (Codec.pcm16WAV)
tested on physical device (recording not supported on simulator)

When I try to play the sound I get
PlatformException (PlatformException(Audio Player, startPlayer failure, null, null))


I sent this question as git issue and this is the replay I got:
https://github.com/Canardoux/flutter_sound/issues/1097
Ι think that you forgot to open an Audio Session with a federating tool like Audio Session.
https://pub.dev/packages/audio_session
You can do something like :
final session = await AudioSession.instance;
await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration(
  avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord,
  avAudioSessionCategoryOptions:
      AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth |
          AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker,
  avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.spokenAudio,
  avAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy:
      AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy.defaultPolicy,
  avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.none,
  androidAudioAttributes: const AndroidAudioAttributes(
    contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.speech,
    flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none,
    usage: AndroidAudioUsage.voiceCommunication,
  ),
  androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gain,
  androidWillPauseWhenDucked: true,
));

